# How to extract all vertexList and texelList of glGenList

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm trying to get **all the texture coordinates** and all the **vertices** of a **`glGenList`**  in two separate lists with c#. I need a function that can do it.
Is this possible?

Comment: Display lists are not something you can read from. It's not entirely clear what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I try get all the vertices and all texture points in  a simple way for not modify much my code. I need a function for get all texture points and  vertices of my scene

Comment: @Martin: What is this scene you're talking about? OpenGL doesn't know what a scene is. A display list is merely a recording of certain OpenGL calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you've created the list, you already have the data. Use that one.